# Group velocity in a waveguide

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, waveguide

I could get the dispersion relation for a wave traveling in a rectangular waveguide of width $a$

$$\omega=c\sqrt{ \left( \frac{\pi}{a}\right)^2 + k_{z}^2  }$$

with $k_z = \dfrac{2\pi}{\lambda_g}\,.$

where z is the direction along the guide. From here I got the group velocity

$$ \dfrac{\partial\omega}{\partial k_z} =  \dfrac{\lambda_0}{\lambda_g}c$$

First of all, is this process correct? And second, I've searched and apparently the guided wavelength is longer than the wavelength in free space, which agrees with the result I got, but I really can't understand how this could happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression of the group velocity $$v_g=\frac {\partial \omega}{\partial k_z}$$ for the waveguide with wave vector $k_z$ in propagation direction is correct. And the phase velocity is $$v_{ph}=\frac{\omega}{k_z}$$ According to the dispersion relation of the wave guide, when $\omega$ approaches the cut-off frequency $\omega_c=c\frac{\pi}{a}$, the wave vector $k_z$ and and group velocity  $v_g$ go to zero and the wavelength approaches infinity.

This can be understood by the fact that the guided wave can be decomposed into plane waves with an inclination angle $\theta$ to the z-direction which are reflected at the upper and lower waveguide walls. If $theta$ approaches 90 degrees, the superposition gives  wavelength in z-direction approaching infinity and there is only a standing plane wave reflected betweeen the upper and lower waveguide wall.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand this concept,  but what I can't wrap my head around is the fact that the wavelength of the component of the wave propagating along the waveguide (in the z direction in this case) $\lambda_g$ seems to be larger than the wavelength of the original wave propagating in free space $\lambda_0$. How can this happen?

Comment: @Julian - The plane wave with wavelength $\lambda_0$, inclined at an angle $\theta $ to the z-axis and its reflection on the side wall inclined at an angle $-\theta$ produces the considered wave mode of the wave guide.  When the plane waves with $\lambda_0$ are directed  at an angle $±\theta$ to the z-direction their crests intersect the z-axis  at a distance $\lambda_ =\frac{\lambda_0}{cos{\theta}}$ which gives the wavelength in z-direction of the waveguide mode.  You can also see this from the projection of the wave vector $ k_{0z} =\vec k_0 \cos{\theta}$ of the plane waves on the z-axis.

Comment: Ohh I see! I was looking at it in a wrong way, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Good question. Guided wavelenght is a somewhat tricky concept. Let's see if we can get some intuition for it.

The group velocity is the straight line velocity of propagation of the wave down the center-line of the waveguide.  Its value is always less than the propagation velocity of the wave in free space ($c$), because the wave propagates along the guide by a series of oblique reflections from one side of the guide to the other, thus increasing the total path length to a value greater than the straight line path.  The relationship between $c$ and $v_g$ is:

$$v_g = c \sin \alpha$$

Where $\alpha$ is the angle of incidence in the waveguide.

On the other hand, we call phase velocity the velocity of propagation of the *spot* on the waveguide wall where the wave impinges. This velocity is actually faster than both $v_g$ and $c$.  It is helpful to consider the “beach analogy” to understand the relationship between the phase and group velocities:

Consider an ocean beach that waves will arrive from offshore at an angle other than 90°, meaning the arriving wave fronts will not be parallel to the shore line.  The arriving waves at $v_g$ as it hits the shore will strike a point down the beach first, and this “point of strike” races up the beach at a faster phase velocity, $v_p$, that is faster than $v_g$.  This is why the phase velocity in a waveguide can be greater than $c$. Finally, consider that the definition of wavelength is the distance between points of equal phase along the wave.

You'll get the following relationship:

$$\frac{v_g}{c}=\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_g}>1$$

Let me know if something is unclear and I'll try to improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting analogy, that was very clear, I appreciate it!